# Does Crypto++ support PKCS#7 padding?

Tags: c++, padding, crypto++

I have tried using AES with CBC mode with PKCS#7 padding, but the result seems to different to what I get from an online AES website program.

The answer should be  `817b c015 a162 57ff 845b fa0c 4dc2 fcbb`, 
what I get was `8fed aeca 2fe9 fa8a 9f35 0468 0258 e80c`

I have read the crypto++ 8.1 manual, and the PKCS_PADDING is for PKCS#5 not for #7
https://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/struct_block_padding_scheme_def.html?fbclid=IwAR18UIE4hi9Menmm6Pze9GBn4loScIGqyTMDel8HujIUChefuIax4hO1u6k#abea06c498771e8f0ad0fbbc19416a979a622df395c2f0edc35f722d938faaad1f

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

#include "cryptopp/modes.h"
#include "cryptopp/aes.h"
#include "cryptopp/filters.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

  byte key[] = {0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36, 0x37, 0x38, 0x39, 0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36};
  byte iv[CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE] = {0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30}; 

  std::string plaintext = "Hello World!";  
  std::string ciphertext;

  CryptoPP::AES::Encryption aesEncryption(key, CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
  CryptoPP::CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Encryption cbcEncryption(aesEncryption, iv);
  CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter stfEncryptor(cbcEncryption, new CryptoPP::StringSink(ciphertext), CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter::PKCS_PADDING);

  stfEncryptor.Put(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(plaintext.c_str()), plaintext.length()+1);
  stfEncryptor.MessageEnd();

  for (int i = 0; i < ciphertext.size(); i++) {
    std::cout << "0x" << std::hex << (0xFF & static_cast<byte>(ciphertext[i])) << "\n"; 
  }

  std::cout << "\n";


  return 0;
}
```

I wonder is there any way to use AES with PKCS#7

Comment: Also see [Commit e8107e9cb8d6](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/commit/e8107e9cb8d6).

Answer (score 1):

> Does Crypto++ support PKCS#7 padding?

Yes. Crypto++ supports PKCS #5, which is used with 64-bit block ciphers. PKCS #7 is used with 128-bit block ciphers, and it is supported. Finally, Crypto++ also supports PKCS padding for large block ciphers, like 256-bit block Kalyna and Threefish. I am not sure what standard governs large block ciphers.

---

> I have tried using AES with CBC mode with PKCS#7 padding, but the result seems to different to what I get from an online AES website program.

It is probably an encoding issue with the web app.

You should use a test vector to cross-validate results. Here is one for AES/CBC from [NIST SP800-38A](https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/sp/800-38a/final):

```
key: 2b7e151628aed2a6abf7158809cf4f3c
iv:  000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f
plaintext:  6bc1bee22e409f96e93d7e117393172a ae2d8a571e03ac9c9eb76fac45af8e51
            30c81c46a35ce411e5fbc1191a0a52ef f69f2445df4f9b17ad2b417be66c3710
ciphertext: 7649abac8119b246cee98e9b12e9197d 5086cb9b507219ee95db113a917678b2
            73bed6b8e3c1743b7116e69e22229516 3ff1caa1681fac09120eca307586e1a7
```

---

> I wonder is there any way to use AES with PKCS#7

You might also be interested in [CBC Mode](https://cryptopp.com/wiki/CBC_Mode) on the Crypto++ wiki.